# Why cant I, in groovy, pass a implementation as argument to a method that takes its interface?

Tags: java, groovy, interface, apache-camel

I'm getting a

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWithBuilder.replaceFromWith() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectEndpoint) values: [direct://start]
```

signature of the method is `AdviceWithBuilder.replaceFromWith(Endpoint ep)`
Im passing in a [DirectEndpoint](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.19.3/org/apache/camel/component/direct/DirectEndpoint.html) that implements Endpoint
I have tried to coerce it to Endpoint

```
@Test
void testSubmitDocument() {
    final Endpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("direct:start",Endpoint.class)
    camelContext.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(camelContext, 
         new AdviceWithRouteBuilder (){
             void configure(){
                 weaveById("bar").replaceFromWith(endpoint)
             }
        } 

    )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because [AdviceWithRouteBuilder.weaveById(String pattern)](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/camel/builder/AdviceWithRouteBuilder.html#line.135) returns [AdviceWithBuilder](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/camel/builder/AdviceWithBuilder.html) and it does not have `replaceFromWith` method.

Comment: right - i forgot to remove the weavebyId after I changed the method I was using there before